# anki software issue

Tags: 14.04

hi  I am no tech wizard so please no tech speak answers

I have purchased a thai language course which uses the following link to download a memory training programme to help learn the language

Linux: http://www.highspeedthai.com/anki/anki-1.0.1.tgz

Problem seems to be my version of ubuntu does seem to pick this up as installable software

the link downloads a zip folder which you extract but from there i cannot seem to get ubuntu to see it as a software programme

this sort of negates the whole programme  so i need this software to work

Any help really appreciated

regards

k

Comment: There's a README file in that archive with instructions on installing. There's also a .desktop file which you should be able to run by double-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've been given is Anki's "Source" which is used to manually compile the application, but that's not necessary.

You can find Ubuntu packages for Anki here: http://ankisrs.net/

*Latest version as of now: http://ankisrs.net/download/mirror/anki-2.0.29.deb*